# Transform dictionary into one column of a dataframe while keeping the dictionary row names in another column (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have several dictionaries which I would like to transform into dataframes.

I am looking for a way to turn the whole dictionary into one row, while keeping the dictionary row name in another column.

Here a short example for clarification. I have a dictionary:

```
example_d= {'R1':[1,2,3,4],'R2':[5,6,7,8],'R3':[10,10,10,10]}
```

which I would like to transform into a dataframe like this:

```
value R_value
0       1      R1
1       2      R1
2       3      R1
3       4      R1
4       5      R2
5       6      R2
6       7      R2
7       8      R2
8      10      R3
9      10      R3
10     10      R3
11     10      R3
```

I tried transformations with the common dict to dataframe commands like

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_d)
```

which did not give the desired result.

Does anyone know a simple way for doing this? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flatten dictionary to list of tuples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(x, k) for k, v in example_d.items() for x in v], 
                   columns = ['value','R_value'])
print (df)
    value R_value
0       1      R1
1       2      R1
2       3      R1
3       4      R1
4       5      R2
5       6      R2
6       7      R2
7       8      R2
8      10      R3
9      10      R3
10     10      R3
11     10      R3
```

Solution for pandas 0.25+:

```
df = pd.Series(example_d).explode().reset_index()
df.columns = ['R_value','value']
print (df)
   R_value value
0       R1     1
1       R1     2
2       R1     3
3       R1     4
4       R2     5
5       R2     6
6       R2     7
7       R2     8
8       R3    10
9       R3    10
10      R3    10
11      R3    10
```